# Ballet-themed TV show with night sky realm

Tags: story-identification, tv

I somewhat recall seeing an animated show in my childhood and have wondered what it was

The show was heavily focused on dance/ballet. It aired on a channel that was availible, though not common, within England at some point around the late 2000s or the 2010s: This channel had other shows focused on dance/ballet

The main character was a white girl. One major thing was that the main character could somehow go to a night-sky type realm. There was also a giant starry swan character, and potentially a similar black swan with a white beak and knob. There may have been other characters in the night-sky place

I didn't see the show very often. I only saw this show at a friend's home, so it's possible that the starry ballet show aired earlier or later than is usual for play-dates/visits. The channel was exclusively for children's shows, if I infer correctly. I do not believe that this channel was CITV, as I recall having access to CITV at my home but never seeing this show there

The swan(s) at least may have been rendered in CGI. The main character might have worn pigtails

I'm quite sure that the show also featured a regular, physical realm in addition to the starry place

The channel on which I saw the show also aired a show involving anthropomorphic mice who did ballet. I saw this other show more often

That's just about all I can recall of this show

Comment: Ballet mice = [Angelina Ballerina](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=XYH2riGoPR0) presumably . It aired on CITV; https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CITV

Comment: _[Princess Tutu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Tutu)_ (2002-2003)...?

Comment: Did Fox try to cash in on the popularity of [Black Swan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Swan_(film)) by making an animated kids tie-in? Were there lunchboxes?

Comment: "I only saw this show at a friend's home" have you conferred with said friend about this?

Comment: @FreeMan I am no longer in contact with them

Comment: too bad... Maybe a reason to renew an old friendship! :D (or, possibly not, your call.)